# Last chess diagram of a \xskakloop is displayed twice

Tags: xskak

The first diagram is the initial position of a chess problem.

The following diagrams are generated within a `\xskakloop`.
However, the last diagram is printed twice.

Why that?

By the way, I would like to start the loop with the initial position.
Setting `\xskakset{moveid=0b}` does not this job.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{xskak}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC4}
\newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
\skaklanguage[german]

\begin{document}

\styleB
\newchessgame[
    id=C,
    setfen=4k2r/1pp1p1p1/p3P2P/8/6P1/1B3P2/nR2P3/1K6,
    moveid=1w
]

\chessboard[smallboard]

\hidemoves{1. Ld5  Sb4 2. h6xg7 Th1#}

\noindent
\xskakset{moveid=1w}%
\xskakloop[step=1, showlast]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \chessboard[smallboard, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
        \\
        \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the 3rd question of you this day, one of them has a good answer, please consider to accept it

Comment: You are printing the board at every step ***and*** printing the last position. So the last one is shown twice. Remove `showlast` to display it only once. Off-topic: better to pass the `a4paper` option to the class and use `geometry` than to load `a4`. Also, better to switch to UTF8 encoding if you can.

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much for the explanation. The hint for using geometry was very helpful, too.

Comment: @PaulGessler I can't: I don't know how to get the loop to start with the initial position. Should I write a partial answer for the other part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial position should be set outside the loop. While it would be theoretical possible to store it as `nextfen` of move 0b, other move related informations (like the `lan` and the number below your board) wouldn't have a sensible meaning.
You want some special (or no) text below the initial board anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{xskak}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC4}
\newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
\skaklanguage[german]

\begin{document}

\styleB
\newchessgame[
    id=C,
    setfen=4k2r/1pp1p1p1/p3P2P/8/6P1/1B3P2/nR2P3/1K6,
    moveid=1w
]

\hidemoves{1. Ld5  Sb4 2. h6xg7 Th1#}

\noindent
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{c}
        \chessboard[smallboard, setfen=\xskakgetgame{initfen}]
        \\
        Initial position
    \end{tabular}
\xskakloop[step=1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \chessboard[smallboard, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
        \\
        \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```